# Non random sequences

Tags: stochastic-processes

In [this pdf](http://faculty.arts.ubc.ca/vmarmer/econ527/527_07.pdf), they introduce something called "non-random" sequences. What does that mean? Other than $X(\omega) = i, \;\forall i.$

Answer (score 1):

In the context of the lecture notes you link to, it appears that the term "non-random sequence" is simply referring to *any* sequence of ordinary, non-random numbers, as opposed to a sequence of [random variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) (which, as the notes point out, are actually functions over the sample space, even if the conventional notation often allows us to treat them more or less as if they were just numbers).